Is it possible to trick a process into thinking it is NOT attached to a tty in C or bash?
There is at least one question about how to trick a process into thinking that it is connected to a TTY when it is not.
I am interested in doing the reverse.
Suppose the command I am invoking is called foobar.
How might I invoke foobar in a way that makes isatty.IsTerminal(stdin) return false?

Here is why I want to do this:

I have a shell script that is executed by the interactive command line tool RpcExplorer.

This shell script is calling a go binary that is based on the exoskeleton library, which uses go-isatty to check whether it is executing in a terminal.

Since it is in fact executing in a terminal, exoskeleton executes the following code, which is causing RpcExplorer to become unresponsive, likely because it is stealing keyboard input from RpcExplorer.
command.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Foreground: true,

        // Ctty must be set to the file descriptor of a TTY when Foreground is set.
        // Its default value is 0, which is the file descriptor of Stdin.
        //
        // We set it explicitly because os.Stdin may be assigned and to avoid confusion.
        Ctty: int(stdin),
}




foobar </dev/null | cat

Instead of faking it, would it be possible to detach from its controlling terminal, as is routinely done by daemon processes?  If you need to reattach later, that should be possible, though it's something I've never tried personally.

@TobySpeight Whether a program's standard input is a terminal is different from the program being attached to a terminal. (I think...)

@chepner, you're right - I was swayed by the introductory sentence ("connected to a TTY") and missed the bit where it's only concerned with stdin.  In which case simply not connecting it to a tty (e.g. foobar <&- or foobar </dev/null, or laundering parent's input using cat|foobar) is much easier than trying to fake something.

There should be no need to trick a program that its standard input is not a tty.  Just connect it to something that isn't a tty, or disconnect it altogether.
Common choices:


foobar <&-

Disconnects the program's input entirely.  Some programs dislike this, so the next alternative is

foobar </dev/null

Connects the input to an empty stream.  But sometimes we need to provide interactive input.  We can do that by laundering through a pipe:

cat -u | foobar

POSIX specifies -u to avoid buffering the flow unduly.


If you can't control how the script is invoked because that's done by some tool, you can redirect the input inside foobar script
#! /bin/bash
exec 0</dev/null
[[ -t 0 ]] || echo 'is not a tty'
...



How might I invoke foobar in a way that makes isatty.IsTerminal(stdin) return false?

Like this:
foobar < <(cat)

